# VS2005 Build app for ARM platform target

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, arm, platform

I need to develop an app for a terminal which runs on Pocket PC 2002. This should be possible using .NET Compact Framework 1.0. But I can't seem to find a way to build the app for use with an ARM CPU. I can only choose x86 or x64 which both do not function (ERROR: 'App' is not a valid Pocket PC application).

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Do you have the Pocket PC 2002 SDK installed?

Comment: @PhonicUK Ahh there is a specific SDK for PPC2002. Sorry that I didn't think of that myself.. May seem stupid, but with all the different versions of CE, PPC and Mobile I couldn't see the wood for the trees anymore. I noticed the different folders including a template folder and a target folder, where to put those (and maybe additional required folders) so that it will function within VS2005?

Comment: You might find that the 2002 SDK only works with VS2003 (or an even older version, not sure)

Comment: @PhonicUK Disregarding the version of VS. Is there a specific place to put the SDK folders? Or should it function right away within VS?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. Last time I used the WinMo SDK it I got a setup package that set everything up for me and it was just a project type that I could select.

Comment: @PhonicUK OK, thanks for your help! I will try to figure it out myself for now.

Comment: Well, only program I seem to get a working app out of if eMbedded Visual Tools 3.0. Which only support C++. Which I don't know anything about, and I do not really have the time to teach myself it. The search for a solution isn't over I guess..